# On delete cascade Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I have two entities that i want to link: `User` and `Folder`

What i want to do is:

- Each folder has a a parent folder (self-referencing)but it is possible to don't have one (null allowed).
- Each user has a default folder (one to one i think) witch doesn't have a parent folder.
- When i delete a user, i want that MySQL automatically delete default folder and subfolders.

The problem I have is i can't delete a User beceause I have a FK.
ErrorMessage :

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`supbox`.`folder`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EB0E0CFB7E3C61F9` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

My entities:

```
<?php   
class User // Supbox\UserBundle\Entity\User
{


    [...]

   /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supbox\CloudBundle\Entity\Folder")
     */
    private $folder;
}


class Folder // Supbox\CloudBundle\Entity\Folder
{


    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Supbox\UserBundle\Entity\User" , cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $owner;

     /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supbox\CloudBundle\Entity\Folder")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent = null;
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `cascade={"remove"}` section to your `$folder` field in User entity.

Comment: Nothing to update on the schema by using `php app/console doctrine:schema:update`